# A SQL Query to select a string between two html tags

Tags: sql-server

I need to get the text between html tags in SQL.

```
< em> " **Test,Extract Me** " < /em>
```

This is just a small part of html body where the unique identifier is < em>"

Please help

Comment: earlier you added the tag with HTML.Now you are tagging with sql server. What is the issue. Please explain proper

Comment: If you're using sql server, it has its own xml query syntax... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/query-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ColumnName,CHARINDEX('html_tag',ColumnName)+LEN('html_tag'),CHARINDEX('html_close_tag',ColumnName)-LEN('html_close_tag')) FROM TableName
```

please replace html_tag,html_close_tag with your tags.

Comment: <h3 class="lead editable" id="intro" style='font-family:"HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; line-height:1.1; margin-bottom:15px; color:#000; font-weight:500; font-size:27px'> <em>"Test 3 response again "</em></h3>

Comment: I want to extract  Test 3 response again

Comment: Please check the Syntax

Comment: SELECT SUBSTRING(ColumnName,CHARINDEX('html_tag',ColumnName) + LEN('html_tag'),CHARINDEX('html_close_tag',ColumnName) -CHARINDEX('html_tag',ColumnName) - LEN('html_close_tag')) FROM TableName

Comment: This works except I am getting " before the text ---  "Test 3 response again

Comment: select   SUBSTRING([Body],CHARINDEX('<em>',[Body]) + LEN('<em>') +1,CHARINDEX('</em>',[Body]) 
  -CHARINDEX('<em>',[Body]) - LEN('</em>')-1) FROM [TSGGMAILREADER].[dbo].[tbl_EmailMessages] 
  where [subject] like '%2945%'

Comment: You can use  like this

SELECT REPLACE( SUBSTRING(ColumnName,CHARINDEX('html_tag',ColumnName) + LEN('html_tag'),CHARINDEX('html_close_tag',ColumnName) -CHARINDEX('html_tag',ColumnName) - LEN('html_close_tag')) FROM TableName), ' " ',' ')

Is this enough to solve your problem?

Comment: `SELECT SUBSTRING(ColumnName,CHARINDEX('html_tag',ColumnName)+LEN('html_tag'),CHARINDEX('html_close_tag',ColumnName) - CHARINDEX('html_tag',ColumnName) - LEN('html_close_tag')+1 )
FROM TableName`

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to take a substring of the column value.
You can try something like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ColumnName, 5, LEN(ColumnName) - 5) AS TrimmedValue FROM TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ColumnName,CHARINDEX('html_tag',ColumnName)+LEN('html_tag'), CHARINDEX('html_close_tag',ColumnName) - CHARINDEX('html_tag',ColumnName) - LEN('html_close_tag') +1) FROM TableName
```

In case the marked answer query doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

With using JQUERY you can find easily with simple one line of code :

```
$('em').text();
```

You can do the same with simple JS as well

```
document.getElementsByTagName('em')[0].innerText
```

Comment: While possibly helpful in other scenarios, This is not an SQL query!